# connect flash in node js not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to register a user in my database using the following register code in the app.js file.

Please see the register route app.post. The problem is that when I run the application it throws an error say that

req is not defined, the line is indicated where I am creating a flash message:

req.flash('error_msg', 'Username already registered');

I tried commenting out this line and then I get the same error only for the next line where its res.redirect function.

It seems that my req and res are not available inside my register function.I am very new to Node so please bear with me :-)

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session =require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
const routes = require('./routes');
const nconf = require('./config');
const setAuthUser = require('./middlewares/setAuthUser');
const neo4jSessionCleanup = require('./middlewares/neo4jSessionCleanup');
const writeError = require('./helpers/response').writeError;

const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const randomstring = require("randomstring");
const _ = require('lodash');


var Users = require('./models/users');
var loginRequired = require('./middlewares/loginRequired');
var dbUtils = require('./neo4j/dbUtils');


const app = express();


  // Body Parser middleware
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  var api = express.Router();

app.use(nconf.get('api_path'), api);

// Flash middleware
app.use(flash());


  //api custom middlewares:
api.use(setAuthUser);
api.use(neo4jSessionCleanup);

  // Handlebars middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main'
  }));
  app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

  // static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//method override middleware
api.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Express Session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

// global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});

// index route
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const title = 'welcome1';
    res.render('index', {
        title: title
    });
});


// User Register Route
    app.get('/users/register', (req, res) => {
        res.render('users/register');
  });

  app.post('/users/register',(req, res,next) => {
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

    if (!username) {
      //throw {username: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
      req.flash('error_msg', 'username field is required');
      res.redirect('/users/register');
    }
    if (!password) {
      //throw {password: 'This field is required.', status: 400};
      req.flash('error_msg', 'password field is required');
      res.redirect('/users/register');
    }

    register(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password)
      .then(response => {
        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
      })
      .catch(next);
  });

//api routes
//api.post('/register', routes.users.register);
api.post('/login', routes.users.login);
api.get('/users/me', routes.users.me);
api.get('/movies', routes.movies.list);
api.get('/movies/recommended', routes.movies.getRecommendedMovies);
api.get('/movies/rated', routes.movies.findMoviesRatedByMe);
api.get('/movies/:id',  routes.movies.findById);
api.get('/movies/genre/:id',  routes.movies.findByGenre);
api.get('/movies/daterange/:start/:end', routes.movies.findMoviesByDateRange);
api.get('/movies/directed_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByDirector);
api.get('/movies/acted_in_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByActor);
api.get('/movies/written_by/:id', routes.movies.findMoviesByWriter);
api.post('/movies/:id/rate', routes.movies.rateMovie);
api.delete('/movies/:id/rate', routes.movies.deleteMovieRating);
api.get('/people', routes.people.list);
api.get('/people/:id', routes.people.findById);
api.get('/people/bacon', routes.people.getBaconPeople);
api.get('/genres', routes.genres.list);

//api error handler
api.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if(err && err.status) {
    writeError(res, err);
  }
  else next(err);
});


var register = function (session, username, password) {
  return session.run('MATCH (user:User {username: {username}}) RETURN user', {username: username})
    .then(results => {
      if (!_.isEmpty(results.records)) {
        //throw {username: 'username already in use', status: 400}
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Username already registered');
        res.redirect('/users/register');
      }
      else {
        return session.run('CREATE (user:User {id: {id}, username: {username}, password: {password}, api_key: {api_key}}) RETURN user',
          {
            id: uuid.v4(),
            username: username,
            password: hashPassword(username, password),
            api_key: randomstring.generate({
              length: 20,
              charset: 'hex'
            })
          }
        ).then(results => {
            return new User(results.records[0].get('user'));
          }
        )
      }
    });
};


const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `req` and `res` are not accessible in the `register` function, they are accessible only in the **middleware**, so you have to pass these objects as arguments :

In the function definition :

```
var register = function (session, username, password, req, res) { ... };
```

In the function call :

```
register(dbUtils.getSession(req), username, password, req, res)
  .then(response => {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  })
  .catch(next);
```

Comment: ...I am now getting another error :

User is not a constructor

I have imported the user model...can you please help with that as well.